# Read a file and split lines in Java.

Tags: java, text, file-io, split

Hello, I want to read a file, file.txt that contains word pairs like this...

```
mot;word 
oui;yes
utiliser;use
comment;how
```

After reading this file.txt , I want to split this text and put the French words in an ArrayList and the English words in an another ArrayList.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why you think this is related to Netbeans?

Comment: Show us what you got in code so far

Comment: are word pairs separated by a space? or are they separated by a new line?

Answer (score 8):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    List<String> frenchList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> englishList = new ArrayList<String>();
    File file = new File("C:/dico.txt");
    if(file.exists()){
        try { 
            list = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(),Charset.defaultCharset());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      if(list.isEmpty())
          return;
    }
    for(String line : list){
        String [] res = line.split(";");
        frenchList.add(res[0]);
        englishList.add(res[1]);
    }
}
```

With this code you have de french word in the list "frenchlist" and the english words in the list "englishlist"

Answer (score 3):

This looks like CSV file. Consider using CSV reader library.

Use [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) function from JDK and read file line by line with [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File)):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = scanner.nextLine();
  // process the line using String#split function
}
```

In `while` loop add splited data to `ArrayList`.

All information are already on stackoverflow.

- [Read String line by line in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096621/how-to-read-a-string-line-per-line)
- [How to split a comma separated String while ignoring escaped commas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820172/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-string-while-ignoring-escaped-commas)
- [Reading File by line instead of word by word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318872/reading-file-by-line-instead-of-word-by-word/20318898#20318898)
- [Read line using Java New I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035981/read-line-using-java-new-i-o)
- [CSV API for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java)

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to create two array lists..

```
    ArrayList<String> english = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> french = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then, open the file, read line by line, split it bye ";" and add the words to ArrayLists...

```
    try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"))){
      String line;
      while((line = in.readLine())!=null){
          String[] pair = line.split(";");
          french.add(pair[0]);
          english.add(pair[1]);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mot;word 
oui;yes
utiliser;use
comment;how
```

It appears that the structure of each line is

```
frenchWord;englishWord
```

So you can read each line of your file using a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) (using the constructor [`Scanner(File source)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29)) and the [`nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) method, and [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) each line by `";"`.

The first element in the array will be the french word and the second one the english word.

Add those element in two separate [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) ([`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) per example), one containing all the french words, and the other one the english words.